# Colorbox bigger than parent

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

On this website: http://www.balbinaarias.com/shop/index.php?route=product/category&path=59
If you click on the images a fancybox opens with the product details.
If you then click on the image, it opens in a bigger modal box, but inside the parent fancybox and you have to scroll.
Is it possible to open the image colorbox outside, as a pure modal colorbox?
I have tried hundreds of parameters but no way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing this page

http://www.balbinaarias.com/shop/catalog/view/javascript/quickview/quickview.js

Change value of locked to true instead of false.

locked: true

Comment: No way. It opens in the first popup and I have to scroll to see the whole image. Still trying. Thank you anyway.